# Incorrectly colored triangles with SDL2-based triangle rasterizer?

Tags: c, sdl, sdl-2

I have been recently working on creating a teapot with C using a pre-made teapot model and just scaling, translating and filling the colors of triangles as well as creating bounding boxes, and it has been going fairly well. However i have gotten this far:

[image]

As you can see its not quite right and i was wondering what ive done wrong? its supposed to look like the image below. Looked over it for hours, and i cant see what i have done wrong. any suggestions?

[image]

Here is my code

**Triangle.C**

```
  // Fill triangle with a color
    void FillTriangle(SDL_Surface *screen, triangle_t *triangle)
    {
        // TODO: Insert code that fills the triangle with the color specified in triangle->fillcolor.
        // Hint: Draw the triangle with color TRIANGLE_PENCOLOR (this color can not
        // occur in e.g. the teapot or the example triangles).  Thus, if your 
        // approach to filling the triangle relies on looking for the edges of
        // the triangle on the screen (via the GetPixel function), you will find those
        // edges even if the triangle overlaps with a triangle that has already
        // been drawn on the screen.
        int maxx,minx,maxy,miny;
        int max(int a, int b){
            if(a>b) return a;
            return b;
        }
        int min(int a, int b){
            if (a<b) return a;
            return b;
        }
        maxx = max(triangle->sx1,max(triangle->sx2,triangle->sx3));
        minx = min(triangle->sx1,min(triangle->sx2,triangle->sx3));
        maxy = max(triangle->sy1,max(triangle->sy2,triangle->sy3));
        miny = min(triangle->sy1,min(triangle->sy2,triangle->sy3));
        int x,y;

           for(y = miny;y < maxy; y++){
            for(x = minx; x < maxx; x++){
                if((triangle->sx1 - triangle->sx2) * (y - triangle->sy1) - (triangle->sy1 - triangle->sy2) * (x - triangle->sx1) > 0 &&
                 (triangle->sx2 - triangle->sx3) * (y - triangle->sy2) - (triangle->sy2 - triangle->sy3) * (x - triangle->sx2) > 0 &&
                 (triangle->sx3 - triangle->sx1) * (y - triangle->sy3) -  (triangle->sy3 - triangle->sy1) * (x - triangle->sx3) > 0)
                {
                    SetPixel(screen,x,y,triangle->fillcolor);
                }
            }
        }



}
```

**Triangle.h**

```
#ifndef TRIANGLE_H_
#define TRIANGLE_H_

typedef struct triangle triangle_t;

struct triangle {
    // Model coordinates
    int x1, y1;
    int x2, y2;
    int x3, y3;

    // Fill color
    unsigned int fillcolor;

    // Scale factor
    float scale;

    // Translate to these coordinates before drawing on screen
    int tx, ty;

    // Bounding box of on-screen coordinates
    int bx, by;         // upper left corner of box
    int bw, bh;         // Width and height of box

    // On-screen coordinates
    int sx1, sy1;
    int sx2, sy2;
    int sx3, sy3;
};

// Draw triangle on screen.
void DrawTriangle(SDL_Surface *screen, triangle_t *triangle);


#endif /*TRIANGLE_H_*/
```

Picture of wireframe (without color)

[image]

Comment: The best way to tackle this is to create a program that draws a single triangle in various non-overlapping configurations to test your triangle rasterizer code.  It's quite clear from your example image that the rasterizer is broken.

Comment: Also note that if this teapot is a full 3d model, you might be attempting to draw hidden triangles as if they were visible.  You might require a depth buffer, or simply use standard vertex winding order to determine visibility.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, i will upload a picture of the wireframe im trying to color, it might be helpful for you.

Comment: From the wireframe it looks like your 2D triangle data is an orthographic projection of the full 3D model.  You can clearly see it contains faces from the back of the teapot.  I strongly suspect that the vertices are correctly ordered, and you are expected to rasterize only those triangles whose vertices are clockwise (or anti-clockwise, depending on what convention is being used).  Been a while since I cared about the math for this, but probably the code inside your double loop depends on a specific ordering of vertices (_i.e._ it's based on the outcome of a cross product).

Comment: "As you can see its not quite right" Not really, I just have some vague ideas. Could you describe the unwanted differences? That would avoid the need of me guessing.